# How to mirror flip animation curves in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, camera

I have a animation that moves my camera from **left to right**. Now I'd like to copy it with 'mirror' transformation so I can use it to move from **right to left**.

Is it possible to do it using script or purely in editor?

Comment: [This script](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/free-mirror-copy-animation-curves.151309/) sounds similar to that—the answer to this might be salvageable from it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When importing the animation there is a 'mirror animation' checkbox under the Animations Tab in the Inspector for that asset.

If you check that box and rename the animation to "myanimation_mirror" or whatever then you should have 2 mirrored animations.

Answer (score 0):

2 Options I'm aware of.

1. Play the same animation but set it to -1 speed. It will play in reverse.

or

2. In the OS, copy the `.anim` file and rename it. Then, open the new animation in Unity and physically swap the keyframes.

Comment: First option is not mirroring or flipping. It's playing the clip backwards.

According to discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543197/how-to-mirror-flip-animation-curves-in-unity I'll need to stick to second option...

Can you describe me how to swap keyframes painlessly please?

Comment: Click and drag the keyframes on the "master" track - the track at the top that doesn't correspond to a specific property.